# Error "NullReferenceException" received when saving changes in EF6 for VB

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, dbcontext

Here is the console app VB.NET code:

```vb
Imports System.Data.Entity
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Configuration

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Using db = New BloggingContext()
            Console.Write("Enter a name for a new Blog: ")
            Dim name = Console.ReadLine()

            Dim blogt As New Blog()
            With blogt
                .Name = name
            End With
            db.Blogs.Add(blogt)
            db.SaveChanges()

            Dim query = From b In db.Blogs
                Order By b.Name

            Console.WriteLine("All blogs in the database:")
            For Each item In query
                Console.WriteLine(item.Name)
            Next

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...")
            Console.ReadKey()
        End Using
    End Sub

    Public Class Blog
        Public Property BlogId() As Integer
        Public Property Name() As String     
    End Class

    Public Class BloggingContext
        Inherits DbContext

        Public Sub New()
            MyBase.New("dbConnString")
        End Sub

        Public Blogs As DbSet(Of Blog)

    End Class

End Module
```

My error points to this line in Main() 'db.Blogs.Add(blogt)' stating "System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

When I mouse over db.Blogs.Add(blogt), it tells me that db.Blogs is nothing. I converted the same code into C# and it works perfectly:

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace CodeFirstNewDatabaseSample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var db = new BloggingContext())
            {
                // Create and save a new Blog 
                Console.Write("Enter a name for a new Blog: ");
                var name = Console.ReadLine();

                var blog = new Blog { Name = name };
                db.Blogs.Add(blog);
                db.SaveChanges();

                // Display all Blogs from the database 
                var query = from b in db.Blogs
                            orderby b.Name
                            select b;

                Console.WriteLine("All blogs in the database:");
                foreach (var item in query)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
                Console.ReadKey();
            } 
        }
    }

    public class Blog
    {
        public int BlogId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual List<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    }

    public class Post
    {
        public int PostId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }

        public int BlogId { get; set; }
        public virtual Blog Blog { get; set; }
    }

    public class BloggingContext : DbContext
    {
        public BloggingContext()
            : base("dbConnString")
        {
            //Database.SetInitializer<BloggingContext>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<BloggingContext>());
        }

        public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Not sure what's missing. I've read all the other EF posts regarding the NullReferenceException error when attempting to SaveChanges, but none have resolved the issue for me yet. Where's Waldo in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Blogs` is not a property in the VB code, it should be:

```
Public Property Blogs As DbSet(Of Blog)
```

Without "Property" it's just a member variable, so it's not automatically initialized by the `DbContext`.

Comment: You are the man! That's exactly what it was and what I was missing. Thank you, I've been scratching my head all day at that.